# c++ explicit contructor not blocking double to int convertion

Tags: c++, explicit

I have a constructor to class C from int and one from double.

I let the first one do implicit type conversion but block the second one using keyword explicit.

but, unfortunately there's a double to int implicit conversion that comes up.. 
Can I block it somehow ?

Here's a simplified example

```
//g++  5.4.0
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
    int* tab;
    public:
    C():tab(nullptr){ cout<<"(void)create zilch\n"; }
    C(int size):tab(new int[size]){ cout<<"(int)create " << size << "\n"; }
    explicit C(double size):tab(new int[(int)size]){ cout<<"(double)create " << size << "\n"; }
    ~C(){ if(tab) {cout<<"destroy\n"; delete[] tab;} else cout <<"destroy zilch\n"; }
};    

int main()
{
    cout << "start\n";
    {
        C o1(1);
        C o2 = 2; //ok, implicit conversion allowed
        C o3(3.0);
        C o4 = 4.0; //ko, implicit conversion to double blocked... but goes to int 
    }
    cout << "stop\n";
}

//trace 
//
//start
//(int)create 1
//(int)create 2
//(double)create 3
//(int)create 4
//destroy
//destroy
//destroy
//destroy
//stop
```

Comment: Unrelated, but important: do not ever use `new` and `delete` in C++. They are low-level operations. In your example, use `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Do you get at least a compiler warning?

Comment: @Mikhail C++ can be a low level language. It's better to say one should prefer not to use them. New and delete still very much have their place.

Comment: the dupe is about how to prevent the conversion in a way that works. If however, your question is actually about why your way does not work, just say. The question could be reopened

Comment: @Mikhail I agree that "never" is an unnecessary exaggeration. Even with smart pointers you have to write the occasional `new`, hence saying "not ever" is misleading.

Comment: @Nick unfortunately no warning at all

Comment: Use of `C(double size)` and then to treat `size` as an `int` is poor design. I would advise explicilty declaring `C(double size)` and `C& operator=(double)` as `private` members and not implementing them.

Comment: @idclev 463035818, sorry... but how do I use your dupe ? I understand that the solution was to overload operator*, so what is the solution here ?

Comment: hm I missed one difference in the questions. Here it seem you want to keep the explicit constructor that takes a double (is that correct?) but prevent the conversion to happen for the other constructor

Comment: in other words: Did you add the explicit constructor only to avoid the other one accepting a `double` or do you actually want to keep both the constructors?

Comment: yes idclev, that's my point : I want 2 constructors, one explicit and the other not. and double to int implicit conversion is messing with my explicit keyword.  by the way, I tried adding "C& operator=(double i){cout << "catch" << endl; }" but it does not help here

Comment: ok reopened. but in that case you should clarify the question a bit. In your example both constructors are doing the same thing (apart from the cout, which i suppose is only for demonstration), so it is not clear why you need both, or why it matters which one gets called

Comment: yes sorry, I tried to bring the example to minimal code. all comments on vector and uselessness of that code are right, but I wished to reduce and focus only on the mechanism at work. Also, I'm totally open to a more meaningful title. If you have any idea, please do change it :)

Comment: `template<typename T> C(T) = delete;` to squelch other implicit conversions.

Comment: @Eljay thanks! works fine. (how do I tag your reply as answer ?)

Comment: My comment was just a comment, and was only an educated guess as to what you were looking for.  However, it does have some caveats because it is a big hammer, and may cause problems (unless you are pedantic about your types).  I don't have time to do a proper answer right now that you could accept on.  Someone will likely provide a comprehensive and explanatory answer shortly.

Comment: guard the C(int) ctor with an enabling type trait, e.g. `template<typename I, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<I>::value>::type> C(I size): tab(new int[size]) {...}`.  You'll need to `#include <type_traits>` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well! **Eljay** got it faster in the comments, but here is the final code that will get you a compiling error trying to use a double implicitly

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
    int* tab;

public:
    //THE TRICK: block any implicit conversion by default
    template <class T> C(T) = delete;

    C():tab(nullptr){ cout<<"(void)create zilch\n"; }
    C(int size):tab(new int[size]){ cout<<"(int)create " << size << "\n"; }
    explicit C(double size):tab(new int[(int)size]){ cout<<"(double)create " << size << "\n"; }
    ~C(){ if(tab) {cout<<"destroy\n"; delete[] tab;} else cout <<"destroy zilch\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "start\n";
    {
        C o1(1);
        C o2 = 2; //ok, implicit conversion allowed
        C o3(3.0);
        C o4 = 4.0; //ko, implicit conversion to other types deleted
        C o5 = (C)5.0; //ok. explicit conversion
    }
    cout << "stop\n";
}
```

Comment: Note that this also blocks the copy and move constructors, so be sure to do those manually :(

Comment: @Mooing Duck Actually not. Those constructors can be used without further work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try replacing the C(int) constructor with one that uses an enabling type trait, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class C{
    int* tab;
    public:
    C():tab(nullptr){ cout<<"(void)create zilch\n"; }
    template<typename I, typename = typename enable_if<is_integral<I>::value>::type>
    C(I size):tab(new int[size]){ cout<<"(int)create " << size << "\n"; }
    explicit C(double size):tab(new int[(int)size]){ cout<<"(double)create " << size << "\n"; }
    ~C(){ if(tab) {cout<<"destroy\n"; delete[] tab;} else cout <<"destroy zilch\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "start\n";
    {
        C o1(1);
        C o2 = 2; //ok, implicit conversion allowed
        C o3(3.0);
        C o4 = 4.0; //ko, implicit conversion to double blocked... but goes to int
    }
    cout << "stop\n";
}
```

This will give you an error like this:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22:16: error: conversion from ‘double’ to non-scalar type ‘C’ requested
         C o4 = 4.0; //ko, implicit conversion to double blocked... but goes to int
                ^
```

Comment: An elegant approach. Just be aware that it will accept a char too: `C c = 'c'`. You could change `is_integral<I>` by `is_same<I, int>` .